# Can a relation that doesn't pass the vertical line test be considered a function from R to a subset of R?

Tags: functions

I understand that a function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ cannot provide more than one value per input without failing to be a function, but what about $g: \mathbb{R} \to X$ or $h: X \to X$ where $X$ is the set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  Can $\sqrt{x}$ be considered a function from $\mathbb{R} \to X$ in this circumstance without restricting its range to only positive numbers since a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is still a single member of $X$?  I'm not sure if I'm missing something or not, but for example when the vertical line test is talked about regarding a relation being a function or not it seems like it's specifically about a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  What am I not understanding?

Comment: Nothing. The vertical line test **is** for functions from subsets of $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$.

Comment: It's not specifically from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but you are correct that each member of the domain can only map to one member of the codomain (or range). Functions are "left total" and "right unique".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. The issue is trickier than may appear at first glance. Your example of the relation $x=y^2$ can be converted to a function $\Bbb R^{\ge0}$ to $\Bbb R^{\ge0}$ just by erasing the lower leg of the parabola. That is, you’ve restricted the target space (codomain) from all of $\Bbb R$ to the nonnegative reals.

But look at the example of the relation $y^2-x-2xy+x^2=0$. Call up Desmos.com and see that it’s a parabola with diagonal axis, so a parabola that’s rotated from its usual opening-up position by $45^\circ$ counterclockwise. In fact if you use Quadratic Formula to solve for $y$, you get $y=x\pm\sqrt x$.

Now, you see what the function is that you want to convert this relation to, it’s just $y=x+\sqrt x$, where as usual the radical means “nonnegative root only”. But you can’t get this from the original relation by refusing to allow certain function-values of your codomain.